# Why use underscore kotlin convention when declaring variables in view model

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, viewmodel

In the view model of the android blueprint example, Google used the following pattern:

```
private val _dialog = MutableLiveData<Dialog>()
val dialog : LiveData<FindaDialogFragment> = _dialog
```

I searched Google for the reason. In conclusion, we restricted access so that fragments and activities could not modify the data in the viewModel.

I understood but could not sympathize. Is there really only one reason?
If so, the code will be longer in viewModel to restrict access to variables.

---

```
private val name = MutableLiveData<String>()
```

also, In 2-way data binding, only MutableLiveData is used.
This is not logical.

I would like to know if there are other reasons for using this pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there really only one reason?

Yes.

> If so, the code will be longer in viewModel to restrict access to variables.

Yes. If you don't want to, you don't have to use it, and could just document it isn't intended to be modified.

> In 2-way data binding, only MutableLiveData is used. This is not logical.

It is; 2-way data binding needs to modify the data, so it needs `MutableLiveData`.

Comment: Then consider accepting the answer https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score -1):

Inside the **ViewModel** class:

The property **_name** (with underscore) *is private and mutable*. Hence, it is only accessible and editable within the ViewModel class.

Outside the ViewModel class:

**name** (without underscore) is public and accessible from other classes like UI controllers. *This property is immutable and read-only.*

---

When an outside class accesses this property, it returns the value of **_name** and its value can't be modified. This backing property protects the app data inside the ViewModel from unwanted and unsafe changes by external classes, but it lets external callers safely access its value.